# Few questions about sml zip function

Tags: list, zip, pattern-matching, tuples, sml

I am new to sml, now I am trying to define a zip function which takes two lists as a tuple.
here are the code.
I got it working, but I have a few questions

```
exception Mismatch;
fun zip ([],[])    = []
| zip ((x::xs),(y::ys)) = (x, y)::zip (xs, ys)
| zip (_, _) = raise Mismatch;
```

Can I define the exception inside zip function, like let in end, I tried, but always get error.

Another question is for the second pattern matching, I wrote

```
zip ([x::xs],[y::ys]) = (x, y)::zip (xs, ys)
```

also gave me error.

Zip take a tuple, but each of the element is list, why can't I use [x::xs] just like other list?

last question, in pattern matching, does the order matter? I think it is, I change the order and got error, just want to make sure

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never define an exception inside of a `let ... in ... end`*. It makes it impossible to catch it by name outside of the `let`-expression.

*: It's okay if you don't plan on letting it escape from the `let`-expression, but you do plan on doing that here.

As for your other question:

When you write `[...]`, the SML compiler understands it as "The list containing `...`."

E.g, `[1]` is the list containing `1`, `[4, 6, 2]` is the list containing `4`, `6` and `2`, and so on.

When you write `x :: xs`, the SML compiler understands it as "The list starting with `x`, followed by the list `xs`."

E.g. `1 :: []` is the list starting with a 1, followed by the empty list, and `4 :: [6, 2]` is the list starting with a 4, followed by `6` and `2`, and so on.

Now, when you write `[x :: xs]`, you're doing a combination of the two, and SML understands it as: "The list containing the list starting with `x`, followed by `xs`."

So, by writing `[...]` rather than `(...)`, you're asking for a list within another list. This is not what you want.

For your final question: Yes, order matters. Patterns are checked in top-down order. Therefore,

```
fun foo _ = 4
  | foo 4 = 5
```

will always return `4`, whereas

```
fun foo 4 = 5
  | foo _ = 4
```

will return `5` when given a `4`.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, so [x::xs] means there are two elements in the list, x and xs?

Comment: `x::xs` means a list containing 1 or more elements. `x` is an element, `xs` is the remaining list.